# Group by but no select

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I know there are tons of Topics like this. But I can not find a solution for this. Maybe there is an other way than Group.

I have this query

```
Select id1, id2, share from table1
```

Result:

```
| id1   | id2  |   share    |
+-------+------+------------+
| 3864  | 3083 |   0.157223 |
| 3864  | 3095 |   0.007548 |
| 57695 | 3095 |   1        |
| 57749 | 2864 |   0.99516  |
```

I want the highest share grouped by `id1` without losing the `id2`

So it should look like this:

```
| id1   | id2  |   share    |
+-------+------+------------+
| 3864  | 3083 |   0.157223 |
| 57695 | 3095 |   1        |
| 57749 | 2864 |   0.99516  |
```

I could do this: `group` only by `id1` and do a join on the old table by `id1` and the share to get the `id2`.

But there must be a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+greatest-n-per-group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries for [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) are typically most efficient using [`distinct on()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in Postgres

```
select distinct on (id) *
from the_table
order by id, share desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.id1 order by t.share desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

In `PostgreSQL` you can use `distinct on` :

```
select distinct on (t.id) t.*
from table t
order by t.id, share desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by id1 order by id2) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```